# What is wrong with this log4j configuration?

Tags: log4j

I'm getting no debug messages and this error message at startup:

`R log4j:ERROR Improper initialization for the appender named [DATEDFILE].`

This is my properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, DATEDFILE, CONSOLE

### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.DATEDFILE=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Prefix=arendeprocess.
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Suffix=.log
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Directory=//localhost/WebsphereLog/PandoraArendeWeb/
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definetely the error of the appender of type biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender.

I think you should check if it's possible to write to the directory **//localhost/WebsphereLog/PandoraArendeWeb/**. Was this directory created? Maybe you need to remove the slash from the end of the path like so:

```
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Directory=//localhost/WebsphereLog/PandoraArendeWeb
```

or even to make path relative like so:

```
log4j.appender.DATEDFILE.Directory=localhost/WebsphereLog/PandoraArendeWeb
```

Comment: thanks but is that the reason why the debug category is failing? My INFO category is working and I did not have the directory but created it now and will investigate further.

Comment: I think that's a reason why biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender is failing. What is or where is your INFO category? I can't see any INFO thresholds in your example.

Comment: It turns out that I was in the wrong project. This was the webapp project and the EJB project also has a log4j config, when I added the debug category to that file then debug messages started coming. So it's alright now, problem is solved.